# DataGridRow ContextMenu with an outer DataContext Command and the DataGrid's SelectedItems CommandParameter

Tags: wpf

I am trying to bind a `Command` to a `ContextMenu` on a `DataGridRow`. The command is on the `Window`'s `DataContext` and I would like to pass as a command parameter the `DataGrid`'s `SelectedItems` property.

I can bind to the VM command using the `Tag` [trick](http://www.spectrecoder.com/?p=51), but I have not been successful with getting `SelectedItems` as a `CommandParameter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work provided that the `DataContext` of the `DataGrid` is the same as the `DataContext` of the parent window where the command property is defined:

```
<DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Test"
                              DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
                              Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext.YourCommand}"
                              CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.SelectedItems}"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
```